# как ускорить одиночный запрос через requests

Tags: python, python-3.x

я делаю запрос к апи сайта
возможно ли ускорить работу request, не асинхронно а именно один запрос?
json ответ весит примерно 1000 кб

request запрос:
в headers

```
headers["cookie"] =""
headers["referer"] =""
headers["user-agent"] = ""
```

использую прокси
работа request без прокси в среднем 0.9 sec
с прокси 1-1.1 sec

Comment: Если сервер хочет отвечать медленно, то вы его никак не ускорите

Comment: Если api позволяет - запрашивать меньше данных, поделить на несколько запросов, их уже выполнить параллельно. Если не позволяет - то никак.

Comment: сам запрос занимает слишком много времени по этому скорость только падает от нескольких запросов

Comment: Ну значит ничего не сделать